# Installing TLS certificate in Flynn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, puma, flynn

How do I set up a SSL certificate for a [Flynn](https://flynn.io) application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer added by @titanous is outdated and is no longer valid.
The correct usage for flynn is:

```
usage: flynn route
   flynn route add http [-s <service>] [-c <tls-cert> -k <tls-key>] [--sticky] [--leader] [--no-leader] [--no-drain-backends] <domain>
   flynn route add tcp [-s <service>] [-p <port>] [--leader] [--no-drain-backends]
   flynn route update <id> [-s <service>] [-c <tls-cert> -k <tls-key>] [--sticky] [--no-sticky] [--leader] [--no-leader]
   flynn route remove <id>
```

So, following the docs, the right answer for this is:

```
flynn -a slashbox route update http/{ID} -c slashbox.crt -k slashbox.key
```

This will print back to you:
`updated {ID}`.

Answer (score 7):

(In the following examples replace `slashbox` with the name of your app)

1. First, you'll need to add the domain:

   `flynn -a slashbox route add http www.slashbox.co`
2. Get the ID of the route:

   `flynn -a slashbox route`

   The ID of the route looks something like `http/xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`
3. Then, add the TLS certificate and TLS key:

   `flynn -a slashbox route update http/xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx --tls-cert cert_chain.pem --tls-key key.pem`

The `cert_chain.pem` file should have the certificate for the domain followed by the intermediate certificate, both in PEM format in the same file. The `key.pem` file should have the unencrypted private key matching the certificate in PEM format.

Sources:

- https://flynn.io/docs/apps#custom-domains
- https://flynn.io/docs/apps#https