# How to route multiple certificates to one Flynn application?

Tags: go, paas, flynn

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755252/installing-tls-certificate-in-flynn) shows how to add a certificate to an application, my question, is there a way to add multiple certificates both non-wildcard and wildcard certificate to a single application.

For example, I have an app called `websites` where it is home to multiple websites, is it possible to set several certificates to this application using Flynn?

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many domains/certificates as you want to an app.

Use the `flynn route add http $DOMAIN -c $CERTIFICATE_PEM_FILE -k $KEY_PEM_FILE` command to add additional routes. You can distinguish between routes in requests to the app by checking the HTTP `Host` header.

Comment: A side question, is Flynn project already abandoned I saw a Github issue stating that it is no longer maintained?

Comment: No, it is not abandoned. We have not had a lot of bandwidth to work on the open source side lately, but there are a bunch of fixes and new features in the pipeline. We run it in production for customers, it is stable and works.

Comment: Then this should be addressed https://github.com/flynn/flynn/issues/4601 because it leaves the impression that "Flynn is not maintained anymore"