# Route multiple SSL certificate into one application

Tags: ssl, dokku

Can Dokku be used to deploy multiple SSL certificates into one application similar to Flynn: [How to route multiple certificates to one Flynn application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799550/how-to-route-multiple-certificates-to-one-flynn-application/62799808#62799808)

Answer (score 1):

At this time, that isn't possible. SSL certificates associated with an app are global, though you can either use a wildcard cert or attach multiple domains when purchasing the certificate. This might be a good future feature, so it's worth writing an issue for it.